# How preg_match function use a variable without declare it first?

Tags: php, function, reference

This is a sample of use for the preg_match function in PHP

```
<?php
preg_match('/(foo)(bar)(baz)/', 'foobarbaz', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

How is possible the function `preg_match` is using the variable `$matches` as a parameter without this being declared first?

Is it wrong if I declare the variable first ?

Comment: It's a reference parameter. The function assigns the variable, it doesn't read its value.

Comment: I can declare a variable inside a function, and *affect* the parent scope ? what is the name of the feature? I would like to read more about it

Comment: In the function definition, the parameter list contains `&$match`. Then anything assigned to that variable is assigned to `$matches`.

Comment: See  [References Explained](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: No, you can't do that yourself without an already declared variable. It's one of a few such occasions where PHP leverages itself to do something you normally wouldn't be able to. Edit: To be clear, you can write functionally equivalent code, but it would raise warnings.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the link, It is so weird, pass as a parameter a variable that doesn't exist, that would throw errors in any other language

Comment: PHP doesn't require you to declare variables in the first place, they're created automatically when needed. Reference parameters are treated like assignments to the variable.